# How to analyze why ReplicasMaxAbsoluteDelay return current time problem?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, clickhouse

Sometimes when the zabbix monitor executes the sql "select value from system.asynchronous_metrics where metric='ReplicasMaxAbsoluteDelay';", it will return a very large value like "52y 9m 18d" (currenttime - 1970).

According to the getAbsoluteDelay() function, we knew when queue_update_finish_time is null, this function will return current_time.

But we want to analyze when and why queue_update_finish_time is null, what can we check from clickhouse system table or log ? We've checked the error log and zookeeper log, but it seems there is no infomation about this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: getAbsoluteDelay() function

https://clickhouse.com/codebrowser/ClickHouse/src/Storages/StorageReplicatedMergeTree.cpp.html#_ZNK2DB26StorageReplicatedMergeTree16getAbsoluteDelayEv

Answer (score 0):

Usually it means table is out-of-sync and gone in read only mode.

Read-only mode can be caused by:

- some zookeeper synchronization issue
- out of disk storage
- stale metadata (replica had failed to apply some alter)
- ...

To get more information try look into `system.replicas` table:

```
SELECT is_readonly, zookeeper_exception 
FROM system.replicas 
WHERE table = 'appsflyer_events_hist'
```

In most cases it helps to run:

```
SYSTEM RESTART REPLICA db.table
```

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/system/#restart-replica